# Erro ao capturar o atributo 'checked'

Tags: javascript, jquery, formulário

JQUERY

```
$('#caption-item-1').click(function(){
    if($('#boleto-input').checked == true){
        $('doacao-proximo-1').css({'display':'inline-block'});
    }else{
        $('doacao-proximo-1').css({'display':'none'});
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<label for="boleto-input">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="boleto-input">
    <span class="check-for-bank"></span>
    <img src="img/barcode.jpg">
</label>
...
<p id="doacao-proximo-1" style="display:none;">Próximo</p>
```

- Não consigo fazer com que, quando o `input` estiver checado, o botão apareça.
- O botão está como `p` porque quando colocado como `button`, a página fica recarregando, mesmo com um `preventDefault()`

Agradeço se puderem me ajudar a resolver, ou encontrar uma forma de resolver o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que te tinhas esquecido de "#" em `$('#doacao-proximo-1')`. Mas Experimenta assim:

```
$('#caption-item-1').click(function(){
    if($('#boleto-input').is(':checked')) { // <-- altera aqui
        $('#doacao-proximo-1').css({'display':'inline-block'});
    }else{
        $('#doacao-proximo-1').css({'display':'none'});
    }
});
```

Comment: perfeito, foi justamente isso mesmo @Miguel

Comment: De nada @MuriloGambôa, foi só uma distração

Answer (score 3):

Bom, já foi respondida, mas deixo aqui uma maneira diferente:

```
$('#caption-item-1').click(function(){
    $('#doacao-proximo-1').css({'display': $('#boleto-input').prop('checked') ? 'inline-block' : 'none'});
});
```